# Multi-dimensional array in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, microcontroller

I have a problem working with multi-dimensional array in C coming from PHP background.

I have an array msg which I am using as input for now. 1st element of array stores 'node_id', 2nd element stores 'actual message' and 3rd element holds 'controller_id'.

Task is handled by function handleSlotMessage(): This function should for each controller_id receive 3 input message (wait until it receives all 3 messages), upon receiving all 3 messages pass it further for processing.

For storing messages, I am trying to use a 'Multi-dimensional array' (which can be simply achieved in PHP): `resultFromNodes` but underlining my limited knowledge of 'C' I am unable to get this done.

For all the usage of resultFromNodes variable in handleSlotMessage function I am getting an error `Subscribed value is not an array, pointer, or vector.`

How can this be implemented in 'C' ? I tried answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647435/how-to-check-if-set-in-c) to check if array is set or not.

```
#define UNINITIALIZED 0xcdcdcdcd


void handleSlotMessage();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int resultFromNodes[99][3] = {UNINITIALIZED};
    int i, j;
    int msg[10];

    // test data only
    for ( i = 1; i < 4; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 1; j < 4; j++ ) {
            msg[0] = j; // sender's id (node id)
            msg[1] = i*j; // message
            msg[2] = i; // controller's id (requester's id)

            handleSlotMessage(msg, *resultFromNodes);

        }
    }
    return 0;
}


void handleSlotMessage(int msg[], int resultsFromNodes[]) {

    // get controller id
    int controller_id = msg[2];
    int node_id = msg[0];
    int message = msg[1];
    int slot_count = 3;

    // check if the resultFromNodes already has controller_id set
    if (resultsFromNodes[controller_id] == UNINITIALIZED) {
        resultsFromNodes[controller_id][0] = slot_count;
    }
    if(resultsFromNodes[controller_id][0] == 0) {
        printf("Message Handled and result from Nodes sent for further processing! \n");
    } else {
        resultsFromNodes[controller_id][node_id] = message;
        printf("on node: %i  msg: %i controller: %i  \n\r", node_id, message, controller_id);
        resultsFromNodes[controller_id][0]--;
    }

    return;
}

EDIT: If this gives any one better idea, 'controller_id' ranges from 1-99 so instead of checking it is set or not it is feasible to check if it is within that range. I don't know if it helps in any way.
```

Comment: This `int resultFromNodes[99][3] = {UNINITIALIZED};` most probably does not do what you might expect. It inits `resultFromNodes[0][0]` with `0xcdcdcdcd` and all other elements with `0`.

Comment: @alk all other element being assigned 0, since I could check if it is 0 or not as well. but the problem is, I cannot assign values to resultsFromNodes[controller_id][0], [1] or any other array, simple assignment shows an error.

Comment: In C reading an uninitialised variable invokes undefined behaviour. Do not do that.

Comment: Thanks, got the idea. I can intialize all array as 0 an carry on, it seems problem was with my function definition, where I used 1-D array for resultFromNodes

Comment: You're treating `resultsFromNodes` in `handleSlotMessage` where it is a declared parameter of type `int[]`, as if it were the same *declaration* in `main()`.

Comment: notice that the check for `slot == 0` need to be after decrementing the variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably wanted to define your function as:

```
void handleSlotMessage(int msg[], int (*resultsFromNodes)[3]) { ... }
```

and to call it as:

```
handleSlotMessage(msg, resultFromNodes);
```

or equivalent:

```
handleSlotMessage(msg, &resultFromNodes[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

there is more than one problem I point some of them

1. Inside  the function  `handleSlotMessage`  the argument `resultsFromNodes` should be declared like `int *resultsFromNodes[4]` in order to be able to send a multi-dimensional arrays of type `int [any number][4]` to it.
   the declaration would be like:

   ```
   void handleSlotMessage(int msg[], int  resultsFromNodes[][4]){...}
   ```
2. to call the `handleSlotMessage` you call it without dereferencing just like:

   ```
   handleSlotMessage(msg, resultFromNodes);
   ```
3. to use the `resultFromNodes` inside the function just like PHP:

   ```
   resultFromNodes[i][j] = 0;
   printf("%i", resultFromNodes[i][j]);
   ```
4. you can't compare subset array with a number or using the notation `{1,2,3}` like:

   ```
   resultFromNodes[n] == 0xCDCDCDCD; // INVALID
   resultFromNodes[n] == {0xCDCDCDCD,0xCDCDCDCD,0xCDCDCDCD}; // INVALID
   ```

   Instead you have to compare each element on its own like:

   ```
   resultFromNodes[n][0] == 0xCDCDCDCD && resultFromNodes[n][1] == 0xCDCDCDCD && 
   resultFromNodes[n][2] == 0xCDCDCDCD && resultFromNodes[n][3] == 0xCDCDCDCD;
   ```

the last thing is that your code has an overflow when accessing the subset arrays of the variable `resultFromNodes`

you are storing the slot_count at `resultFromNodes[controller_id][0]`
and the counter `j` represents `node_id` will have the values `1,2,3` 
hence `4` elements in total you have only 3 element:

```
resultFromNodes[controller_id][0] = slot_count;
resultFromNodes[controller_id][1] = node_id;    // j=1
resultFromNodes[controller_id][2] = node_id;    // j=2
resultFromNodes[controller_id][3] = node_id;    // j=3
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized all of the error and fixed it, since I am new to c, I am real sloppy. Well thank you once again.

Comment: also regarding your function declaration, I don't know why but it seems *resultsFromNodes needs to be within () int (*resultsFromNodes) [4]){...}

Answer (score 1):

```
        resultsFromNodes[controller_id][0] = slot_count;
```

`resultsFromNodes` is declared as a 1-D array, but you give it a second subscript `[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I had this error, resultFromNodes on function definition declared as 1-D array and few other mistake that I realized from other answer and comment. Thank you!